# DialogFragment: Show first dialog, on positive button, show second dialog and on second dialog show the first dialog again

Tags: java, android

I have a DialogFragment class like this:

```
 public static class InputPasswordDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        mBuilder.setTitle("Authentication Required");
        mBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.fingerprint);
        View mView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.management_password_dialog, null);
        mBuilder.setView(mView);
        mBuilder.setPositiveButton("LOG-IN", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            // LOGIN BUTTON HERE
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // I WANT TO SHOW ANOTHER DIALOG (ERROR DIALOG)
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("Password Error")
                        .setMessage("Password is incorrect. Please try again!")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // I WANT TO GO BACK TO THE PREVIOUS MAIN DIALOG
                                getDialog().show();
                            }
                        }).show();
            }
        });
        mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
        });
        AlertDialog ad = mBuilder.create();
        return ad;
    }

}
```

This is what I want to happen.

1. Show the 1st dialog which is an authentication password box dialog.
2. On Positive Button Click ("OK Button"):
3. Show another dialog which is an "Error Dialog".
4. On Positive Button Click on the "Error Dialog", go back to the first dialog.

It returns this exception:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Dialog.show()' on a null object reference` when i click the positive button of the second dialog which supposed to be returning to the first main password dialog.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: show first dialog -> dismiss it and show second -> dismiss second and show first again

Answer (score 0):

So i solved the problem by:

1. Creating a null value for both password dialog and error dialog outside the onCreate method.
2. Declaring the value of the password dialog and error dialog in the onCreate method.
3. Show the first dialog (password dialog) on DialogFragment show method from the activity.
4. On error, dismiss the first dialog, and show the second dialog (error dialog) using the errorDialog.show() method
5. On second dialog OK button, dismiss the errorDialog and show the first dialog using the ad.show() method.

   ```
   public static class InputPasswordDialog extends DialogFragment {

   public Dialog ad = null;
   public Dialog errorDialog = null;
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setRetainInstance(true);
       setCancelable(false);
       errorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
               .setTitle("Password Error")
               .setMessage("Password is incorrect. Please try again!")
               .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // I WANT TO GO BACK TO THE PREVIOUS MAIN DIALOG
                       dialog.dismiss();
                      ad.show();
                   }
               }).create();
       errorDialog.setCancelable(false);


       AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
       mBuilder.setTitle("Authentication Required");
       mBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.fingerprint);
       View mView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.management_password_dialog, null);
       mBuilder.setView(mView);
       mBuilder.setPositiveButton("LOG-IN", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           // LOGIN BUTTON HERE
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // I WANT TO SHOW ANOTHER DIALOG (ERROR DIALOG)
               dialog.dismiss();

               // SHOW ERROR DIALOG OR SUCCESS LOGIN
               String password = "password";
               if (password.equals(password))
                   ((Management)getActivity()).showManagement();
               else
                   errorDialog.show();
           }
       });
       mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               dialog.dismiss();
               getActivity().finish();
           }
       });
       ad = mBuilder.create();
       return ad;
   }

   }
   ```